# file_get_contents produces error message

Tags: php

i want to read the sourcecode of another webpage and receive the following error using file_get_contents in PHP:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(url is here) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in file_get.php
```

How is this possible and is there a solution to work around this?

Thanks.

Comment: Food for thought: You won't get any response if you don't post your actual code. Actually that's not entirely true, you will get a response, some of which will end up as being "downvotes", which I for one, did NOT downvote but you can expect more till you do.

Comment: You could always try to use an `iframe` to "display" content, but that's not always a sure fire way. FYI: Google and other sites as such won't show up using `iframes`, if that's your intention.

Answer (score 3):

The error message sums it up nicely:

> HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden

You do not have permission to access that page. It is controlled by the host you're trying to scrape.

For more information, see [HTTP 403](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) on Wikipedia.

Comment: 'tis the "hard & harsh reality" of it all. (Oh, the humanity).